# unable to run perl prove with --debug option

Tags: perl, tap, perl-prove

I tried to run prove with -d option, but got error:

```
Cannot detect source of '-d'! at /usr/coderyte/lib/perl5/5.8.8/TAP
/Parser/IteratorFactory.pm line 263
```

now 'man prove' does not show the -d switch available, but http://perldoc.perl.org/5.8.8/prove.html

clearly shows --debug

Is that a documentation error, or a prove issue ? 
Is there a way, i can use -debug with prove ?
I am using:

```
$prove -V
TAP::Harness v3.28 and Perl v5.8.8
```

Comment: You can check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42816534/4632019

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `--debug` option was [removed from `prove` in 2007](https://github.com/Perl-Toolchain-Gang/Test-Harness/commit/03276cec53ffd2fa124dfa276a5f3fd5e6495dd1).  The version of `prove` originally shipped with Perl 5.8.8 had one, but you've since installed a newer version ([from Test-Harness 3.28](https://metacpan.org/release/OVID/Test-Harness-3.28/)).

Why do you think you need to use `-d`?  Are you looking for the `--verbose` (or `-v`) option?

Comment: the reason why i needed to use -d option, was 1. Maybe debug would give me more info on errors, maybe debug trace 2. The documentation (as i mentioned in the URL) displayed debug as well as verbose, so what is the difference ? in general if an option is available, i generally check it out ( i dont think that is a bad thing , right ?)

Comment: Perhaps the OP wanted to use `-d` so as to get what `perl -d` would do – i.e. to engage the debugger and be able to stop execution as desired, examine values & data structures, run commands, and generally figure out what was going on? You know... debug stuff.