# How to run perl test in debugger mode?

Tags: perl, testing, perl-prove

I try to run test under debugger as:

```
perl -d $(which prove) t/file.t
```

But this has no effect because each test is run as separate job.

I have found `--exec` option, but when I provide it I lost any option from `.proverc` file and command line

```
prove -Ithis/is/lost --exec 'perl -d' t/file.t
```

**How to run tests by `prove` with additional options** and do not lose those options which were provided at `.proverc` file and command line?

I do not want repeat myself and write:

```
prove --exec 'perl -d -Ilib -Ilocal/lib/perl5' t/file.t
```

While `-Ilib` and `-Ilocal/lib/perl5` are both at `.proverc` file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can repeat yourself once if you set the `PERL5OPT` environment variable.

```
export DBG_MODE='-d -Ilib -Ilocal/lib/perl5'
prove t/file1.t                       # regular use
PERL5OPT=$DBG_MODE prove t/file2.t    # with debugger
```

or with an alias or bash function

```
alias proved='PERL5OPT="-d -Ilib -Ilocal/lib/perl5" prove'
```

Comment: I have tried it too. It did not work, because it will run two debuggers. One for prove and second for test. I setup port to debug remotely, but because of two debuggers are run I got conflict about that port is in use and scenario dies (